# Get better results with SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

SpeechRecognitionEngine works pretty well, if I have to loaded grammars it always select the correct one. But if I say something completly different than the two loaded grammar it will trigger any of the loaded grammars. How can i make it trigger if I only say one of the loaded grammars?

My code looks like this for loading grammar

```
var builder = new GrammarBuilder(text);
recognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(builder));
```

Full code
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/Speech/FreePIE.Core.Plugins/SpeechPlugin.cs

Comment: The link gives a 404 now. Is this the new location? https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core.Plugins/SpeechPlugin.cs

Comment: btw, this is the line that got it better, also run the wizard to learn it recognize better https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core.Plugins/SpeechPlugin.cs#L91

Comment: If that line helped you out, you can post that as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the confidence level, you can also make it better by using the Wizard and  teach the RecognitionEngine to be more accurate